# How to create an array of array list?

Tags: java, arrays, list

Hello I just had a question about a sorting problem I’m working through. I need to take a list a words and sort them by the first character. So basically I’m creating an array of each letter with a list inside the list. For example at position 0 of the array I could have a list of words that start with A. For position 1 it would be words that start with b. I figured out how to do this by hardcover a bunch of if statements for each letter. I guess my question is, is there a simpler way of achieving this without having to hardcode 27 if statements for each letter?

Comment: Use a `Map<Character, List<String>>`. No need to use any if statement.

Comment: Show an example of your starting point. Do you have a `String` containing words? Or do you have a `List` or one-word strings?

Answer (score 2):

This is nicely done with the Java Streams API. The operation you ask for is called *grouping (by)*.

The code below will stream over all elements of the array created by `split`, putting the elements in groups defined by a given function. The code below uses `str -> str.charAt(0)` as function, which basically says "from element *str*, get the first character, and this identifies the group", that is, the *key*.

```
Map<Character, List<String>> map = Arrays.stream(line.split(" "))
    .groupingBy(str -> str.charAt(0));
```

---

The abovementioned code uses the *functional programming* style. Not everyone is familiar with this style, so below you'll find a solution using traditional style.

```
Map<Character, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
String[] words = line.split(" ");
for (String word : words) {
    char first = word.charAt(0);
    if (!map.containsKey(first)) {
        map.put(first, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    map.get(first).add(word);
}
```

#### Why a map? Why not just an ArrayList?

A map has better lookup performance (time complexity of *O(1)*), while using a List requires you to traverse the list (time complexity *O(n)*).

---

*Using `charAt(0)` I assume that none of the words is empty, i.e. has a length of 0.*

Comment: This assumes the list of words is actually one big string separated by spaces. If your list of words is already a `List<String>`, then it's simply `words.stream().groupingBy(str->str.charAt(0));`

Comment: @BasilBourque Yes, I was planning to. I'll include that in the answer.